# Can't compile less files with web essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

As of lately I cannot compile my less files with web essentials. All menu choices are disabled.

[image]

The latest version of WE is installed a well as the latest update of VS 2013.
What can I do do make these options available again?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is a bug with LESS files in the latest version of Web Essentials v2.5.2. Here's an Issue report from GitHub:

https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1665

From the issue, folks rolled back to v2.5 and were then able to use LESS files again. There is a link to get the 2.5 version in the GitHub issue.